# Problema al imprimir elementos de una arreglo con punteros

Tags: c++, array, bucle-for, punteros, comparaciones

Mi código pide datos y los llena al arreglo.

Luego comprueba si son pares.

Y debe imprimir los datos que son pares.

El llenado de datos si lo hace correctamente.

Pero al momento de imprimir solo
me sale esto - **El numero 0 en la posición [0] es par**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int arreglo[5];
    int *p;

    p = &arreglo[0];
    
    //Pide datos al usuario

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese un numero: ";
        cin>>*p++;
    }

    cout<<endl;

    //Comprueba si son pares y los imprime
    
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(*p%2 == 0){
            cout<<"El numero "<<*p++<<" en la posicion ["<<i<<"] es par\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando punteros innecesariamente. Es gracioso que la mayoría de gente tenga una irracional fobia a los punteros pero en tu caso pareces tener una irracional afinidad a ellos.

En esta parte de tu código:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese un numero: ";
    cin>>*p++;
}
```

El puntero `p` avanza cinco posiciones, empieza así:

```
        +-+-+-+-+-+
arreglo |0|1|2|3|4|
        +-+-+-+-+-+
         ^
         p
```

Y acaba así:

```
        +-+-+-+-+-+
arreglo |0|1|2|3|4| _.·^ Aquí hay dragones ^·._
        +-+-+-+-+-+
                   ^
                   p
```

Como puedes ver, `p` está fuera de `arreglo` al finalizar tu primer bucle, por lo que al recorrer tu segundo bucle, la situación empeora, empieza así:

```
        +-+-+-+-+-+
arreglo |0|1|2|3|4| terreno desconocido
        +-+-+-+-+-+
                   ^
                   p
```

Y acaba así:

```
        +-+-+-+-+-+
arreglo |0|1|2|3|4| tierra de nadie
        +-+-+-+-+-+
                               ^
                               p
```

---

Si realmente tienes tanto apego a los punteros, puedes cambiar tus bucles de la siguiente manera:

```
for (int *inicio = arreglo, *fin = arreglo + 5; inicio != fin; ++inicio) {
    cout << "Ingrese un numero: ";
    cin >> *inicio;
}

for (int *inicio = arreglo, *fin = arreglo + 5; inicio != fin; ++inicio) {
    if (*inicio % 2 == 0) {
        cout << "El numero "
             << *inicio
             << " en la posicion ["
             << (5 - (fin - inicio))
             << "] es par\n";
    }
}
```

Pero en realidad no es necesaria tanta afinidad a los punteros en este caso, puedes usar índices:

```
for (int indice = 0; indice != 5; ++indice) {
    cout << "Ingrese un numero: ";
    cin >> arreglo[indice];
}

for (int indice = 0; indice != 5; ++indice) {
    if (arreglo[indice] % 2 == 0) {
        cout << "El numero "
             << arreglo[indice]
             << " en la posicion ["
             << indice
             << "] es par\n";
    }
}
```

Incluso puedes omitir los índices completamente en el primer bucle y parcialmente en el segundo:

```
for (auto &valor : arreglo) {
    cout << "Ingrese un numero: ";
    cin >> valor;
}

int indice = 0;
for (const auto &valor : arreglo) {
    if (valor % 2 == 0) {
        cout << "El numero " << valor << " en la posicion [" << indice++ << "] es par\n";
    }
}
```

---

[Aquí hay dragones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hic_sunt_dracones).

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema, es después de la lectura, donde queda apuntando el puntero.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int arreglo[5];
    int *p;

    p = &arreglo[0];
    
    //Pide datos al usuario

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese un numero: ";
        cin>>*p++;
    }
  
    cout <<" El puntero apunta a :" << *(p-1); <-- fíjate en lo que imprime.
    cout<<endl;

    //Comprueba si son pares y los imprime
    
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(*p%2 == 0){
            cout<<"El numero "<<*p++<<" en la posicion ["<<i<<"] es par\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

¿Cómo lo puedes solucionar? Haciendo que p siempre apunte a la posición cero, añadiendo las posiciones del array que debe moverse, dentro de cada bucle.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int n_datos = 5;
    int arreglo[n_datos];
    int *p;

    p = arreglo;
    
    //Pide datos al usuario

    for(int i=0;i<n_datos;i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese un numero: ";
        cin>>*(p+i);
    }
    //Comprueba si son pares y los imprime
    
    for(int i=0;i<n_datos;i++){
        if(*(p+i)%2 == 0){
            cout<<"El numero "<<*(p+i)<<" en la posicion ["<<i<<"] es par\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes echarle un vistazo a éste enlace:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208021/how-to-increment-a-pointer-address-and-pointers-value

Answer (score 1):

El origen del problema ya te lo han explicado... incrementas `p` y se queda apuntando más allá de la última posición del array.

Una solución alternativa pasa por reiniciar antes de empezar el segundo bucle:

```
int arreglo[5];
int *p = arreglo;

//Pide datos al usuario

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese un numero: ";
    cin>>*p++;
}

cout<<endl;

p = arreglo; // Hacemos que p vuelva a apuntar al inicio del array

//Comprueba si son pares y los imprime
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    if(*p%2 == 0){
        cout<<"El numero "<<*p++<<" en la posicion ["<<i<<"] es par\n";
    }
}
```

Esto soluciona tu error a medias... ya que tu código tiene un segundo error: No incrementas el puntero `p` si el valor apuntado es impar:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    if(*p%2 == 0){
        cout<<"El numero "<<*p++<<" en la posicion ["<<i<<"] es par\n";
        //                    ^^ Este incremento solo se realiza si *p es par
    }
}
```

La solución pasa por incrementar **siempre** el valor de `p`

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++,p++){
//                  ^^^ Incrementamos p en cada iteración
    if(*p%2 == 0){
        cout<<"El numero "<<*p<<" en la posicion ["<<i<<"] es par\n";
    }
}
```